# FOSElasticaBundle sort not working

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

The configuration of my elastica type looks like following:

```
            acme_article:
                mappings:
                    title: {type:string, index_analyzer:acme_analyzer}
                    content: {type:string, index_analyzer:acme_analyzer}
                    slug: ~
                    media: {type:string, index_analyzer:acme_analyzer}
                    categories:
                        type: "object"
                        properties:
                            name: ~
                            id: ~
                    instance:
                        type: "object"
                        properties:
                            name: ~
                    created_by: ~
                    created_at: ~
```

I have Repository class which extends FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository and everything works well except sorting.

```
    $query = new \Elastica\Query();
    $query->setSort(array('created_at' => array('order' => 'desc')));        
    return $this->find($query);
```

Getting some irelevant result, totally  without order. Then, I tried to add model id in index and try to sort by id but also without success.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to set {type:date} on created_at field. In that case ES sorting by timestamp and everything is ok.

Sorting by id is not working because in some way categories.id override main id and then I got results ordered by category.id instead entity id.